# NullPointerException while trying to populate a list in a fragment

Tags: java, android, database, fragment, populate

I've been trying to populate a ListView from a database within a fragment in Android. Unfortunately, when starting the app, I get `NullPointerException` while it is trying to populate & create my list. 
The code in which I am getting the `NullPointerException`

```
public class AlarmFrag extends Fragment {

    List<UserInputAlarmData> UserInputAlarmData = new ArrayList<UserInputAlarmData>();
    DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
    ListView AlarmListView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_alarm, container, false);
        AlarmListView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.AlarmListView);
        return rootView;

    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

        List<UserInputAlarmData> addableAlarmData = dbHandler.getAllAlarmData();
        int AlarmDataCount = dbHandler.getAlarmDataCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < AlarmDataCount; i++) {
            UserInputAlarmData.add(addableAlarmData.get(i));
        }

        if (!addableAlarmData.isEmpty())
            populateList();
    }

    private void populateList() {
        ArrayAdapter<UserInputAlarmData> adapter = new AlarmListAdapter();
        AlarmListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void AddAlarm(int id, String name, String phone, String email, String address) {
        UserInputAlarmData.add(new UserInputAlarmData(id, name, phone, email, address));
    }


    private class AlarmListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserInputAlarmData> {
        public AlarmListAdapter() {
            super(getActivity(), R.layout.alarm_view_item, UserInputAlarmData);

        }
    }
}
```

The referenced frag_alarm.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#363">

<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="AlarmScreen"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:text="Add New Alarm"
        android:id="@+id/AlarmSetupButton"
        android:onClick="AlarmSetupButtonClick"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/AlarmListView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Referenced alarm_view_item.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Alarm Title:"
        android:id="@+id/TitleName"
        android:layout_weight="0.03" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Time:"
        android:id="@+id/TimeName" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Date:"
        android:id="@+id/DateName" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Song:"
        android:id="@+id/SongName" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat providing crash report.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.goldin.foodtektrakr.AlarmFrag.populateList(AlarmFrag.java:49)
            at com.goldin.foodtektrakr.AlarmFrag.onCreate(AlarmFrag.java:44)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1763)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:913)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12752)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12752)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12752)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2267)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12752)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1074)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2462)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4532)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you in advanced for the help. I can provide any other class or xml files which are needed to sort out the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: what is line no 49 in AlarmFrag.java?

Comment: Line 49 is:  AlarmListView.setAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onCreateView()` method is called after `onCreate()`. When you call your `populateList()` method from `onCreate()`, your `AlarmListView` has not been initialized yet. So, simply move the call to `onCreateView()` method to fix your issue.

The complete `Fragment` lifecycle is as follows:

[image: Fragment Lifecycle]

---

> I am now getting another error unfortunately: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Instantiate your `AlarmListAdapter` as

```
private class AlarmListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserInputAlarmData> {
    public AlarmListAdapter() {
        super(getActivity(),
              R.layout.alarm_view_item,
              R.id.TitleName, // Passing TextView id
              UserInputAlarmData);
    }
}
```

Although, this would get rid of the error but it wouldn't do quite what you're hoping for. I see that you have four `TextView`s within your *row item layout*, but an `ArrayAdapter` can bind text to only one of those. Since, we passed `R.id.TitleName` there, the *adpater* will bind the text to the first `TextView` only.

To split your *adpater* item and display data in multiple *views* that make the *list item*, you would need to extend the `ArrayAdapter` class and implement `getView()`. Here's one of the many tutorials available online that show how to implement one: [ListView with Custom Adpater](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/listview-with-custom-adapter.html).

Comment: I am probably doing this totally wrong, but when I move the onCreateView method, I am still getting the exact same error message.

Comment: You can move all of your `onCreate()` code to `onCreateView()` because all of it pertains to adapter only. If that doesn't help, update your post with how your code looks now with the stacktracte.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am now getting another error unfortunately:  ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized your `ListView AlarmListView;` So default value of any reference variable is `null` that is why you are getting `Null Pointer Exception`

So when you call this line

```
AlarmListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

it is actually

```
null.setAdapter(adapter);
 /\
 ||
 So Null Pointer Exception
```

Comment: He has initialised...`AlarmListView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.AlarmListView);` check the code once more..